# Serializing and Deserializing Object Arrays in Kryo

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, kryo

I've been testing Kryo for serialization and deserialization recently and have generally been happy with it, however it is not clear to be how to handle the (de)serialization of a class which contains an object array. The class contains final fields, so I don't seem to be able to use the default FieldSerializer (The error being "Class cannot be created (missing no-arg constructor)", but a no-arg constructor being inappropriate for a final primitive). So, given the class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DataObject{
     private final double field1;
     private final double field2;
     private SubObject[] children;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
public class SubObject{
     private final double field1;
     private final double field2;
}
```

How would one efficiently write a serializer/deserializer to handle this? My assumption is that I'm missing something in com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input which will let me do this in a custom serializer, but that might be the wrong track..

Comment: What is the problem with just using kryo.writeObject() and kryo.readObject? That is, why do you need to write your own serialization on top of Kyro anyway?

Comment: have the same problem (

Answer (score 2):

question was asked 3 years ago, so this is kinda silly to write answer for it, but I found a solution, described directly in `kryo`'s readme file

here is a [link](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#object-creation)

Basically when you serializing object by simple call of `writeObject(Output, Object)` without providing your own serializer, `kryo` uses default `FieldSerializer` that requires non argument constructor.

You can provide private non argument constructor which `kryo` will invoke using `reflection` mechanism. I think it's suitable way to do, what you wanted because private zero argument constructor doesn't violates architecture principles